# Unit testing in struts 2: Not able to inherit protected variables

Tags: java, unit-testing, struts2

I have a weird problem. I created a test class by extending `StrutsTestCase`.

```
   public class MyActionTest extends StrutsTestCase{

      public void helloTest()
      {

      }
  }
```

The struts documentation says `request` of `MockHttpServletRequest` will be available by extending `StrutsTestCase`. Fair enough, it's a protected variable in `StrutsTestCase` so we should have access to it once we extend the class.

But for some reason, NO protected attribute or method of `StrutsTestCase` is visible in my `MyActionTest`.

I don't know if I am missing something, but everything seems straight forward, but yet doesn't work.

Any idea as to why the protected methods of super class are not accessible in subclass ? Should I use some specific package or something ?

List of jars I use for this task :

1. spring-2.5.3.jar
2. spring-mock-1.2.6.jar
3. struts2-core-2.0.11.jar
4. xwork-core-2.3.1.jar

Am I missing  something ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps struts2-junit-plugin http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/junit-plugin.html or struts2-testng-plugin http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/testng-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

StrutsTestCase is part of the struts2-junit-plugin. See http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/struts2-plugins/struts2-junit-plugin/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/StrutsTestCase.html - you'll find the protected request variable there.

Just add that plugin to your classpath and you should be able to use it. Also, don't forget to use the same versions for your struts-core and the plugin.